# How to change Active Directory user display name using Python

Tags: python, pyad

I have a Python script which read a PDF document and create an AD user account related the data it gets. I want in directory shown as John Doe instead of user account jdoe. Here what I have done so far:

```
from pyad import *

firstname = 'John'
lastname = 'Doe'
username = firstname[0].lower() + lastname.lower()
displayname = firstname + ' ' + lastname
password = 'Secret124!'

pyad.set_defaults(ldap_server="dcx", username="admin", password="Secret")
ou = pyad.adcontainer.ADContainer.from_dn("OU=Test-accounts, DC=company, DC=com")
new_user = pyad.aduser.ADUser.create(username, ou, password=password, 
    optional_attributes={
    'givenname' : firstname,
    'sAMAccountName' : username,
    'displayName' : displayname,
    'sn' : lastname
    })

new_user.update_attribute('displayName', displayname)
```

That runs without error but the displayName is still jdoe. How to change that using Python?

[image: John Doe as in AD]

Answer (score 0):

I changed the method using a displayname as useraccount and then give username as attributes. See below:

```
from pyad import *

firstname = 'John'
lastname = 'Doe'
username = firstname[0].lower() + lastname.lower()
displayname = firstname + ' ' + lastname
password = 'Secret124!'

pyad.set_defaults(ldap_server="dcx", username="admin", password="Secret")
ou = pyad.adcontainer.ADContainer.from_dn("OU=Test-accounts, DC=company, DC=com")
new_user = pyad.aduser.ADUser.create(displayname, ou, password=password, 
    optional_attributes={
    'givenname' : firstname,
    'sAMAccountName' : username,
    'userPrincipalName' : username + '@company.com',
    'displayName' : displayname,
    'sn' : lastname
    })
```